# Find all blur() events executed for any element on page load

Tags: jquery, firebug, monkeypatching

I am working with a HTML/jQuery page that somebody else wrote a while ago. For debugging I need to find all `.blur()` events that are triggered for any element on page load.

I can use the following to bind an event to all elements:

```
$("*").each(function() {
     $(this).blur(function() {
         alert(this);
     });
});
```

However this will not work (even if I could run it before the page loads), since the scripts on the page rebind `.blur()` events anyway.

Is there a way I can see what .blur() events are executed on page load? I thought I might be able to overwrite the `.blur()` internal jQuery function at run-time without this getting overwritten by blur event bindings but not sure if it's possible.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what it is you're asking. Do you want to attach your own `blur` event to all elements (how does this help with debugging?)? Do you want a list of all elements that have `blur` event handlers attached to them? Or do you want to know which elements have their `blur` event handlers triggered after the page is done loading?

Comment: @Anthony The third option is exactly what I need to do :)

Comment: In that case, @RobW's answer **may** do what you need. Calling `.blur()` (or `.click()`, etc) on an element more than once doesn't overwrite the handlers that were previously added. However, if the existing jQuery code does (for whatever reason) do `$('selector').unbind('blur').blur(function(e) {...});` you may run into problems with finding the correct place to attach your generic handler.

Comment: Actually, just to clarify - are we talking programmatically triggered (ie. `$('selector').trigger('blur');` or `$('selector').blur()`) or triggered through user interaction with the page?

Comment: @Anthony programmatically triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the `blur` event to `document` using [`.on('blur', '*', ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery 1.7+):

```
$(document).on('blur', '*', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Otherwise, many alerts will pop up for each event
    alert(this);
});
```

If you don't have jQuery 1.7+, use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead:

```
$(document).delegate('*', 'blur', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Otherwise, many alerts will pop up for each event
    alert(this);
});
```